# why i can't print char type value with my output

Tags: java

```
package practice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shuvo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("please Enter your name: ");
        char name;
        Scanner user= new Scanner(System.in);
         name = user.next().charAt('0');
        System.out.println("HELLOW" +name); //<- why this isn't working??
        user.close();
    }
}
```

output:

please Enter your name: shuvo

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 48

```
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at practice.Shuvo.main(Shuvo.java:11)
```

Comment: Thank u but i want to know when i write "System.out.println("hellow"+name) " the output show me "hellow shuvo". but it dose not working. how dose i have this output and why this is not working?

Answer (score 3):

`user.next().charAt('0');` will return the character that corresponds to the index with number `'0'`.

`'0'` is of `char` type, which is actually numeric, and its decimal value is `48`. As you input doesn't have 48 characters, you get the `ArrayIndexOfOfBoundsException`.

Use:

```
user.next().charAt(0);
```

which will return you the first character from the input.

Answer (score 0):

or simply

```
char name=user.next().charAt(0);
```